# Understanding a sequence generation formula of the A064532

Tags: oeis

I'm trying to understand the formula presented for the sequence [A064532](https://oeis.org/A064532) from the OEIS, looks like a recurrence relation with complex numbers:

$a(10i+j) = a(i) + a(j), etc.$

Sorry if its a simple equation, but I wasn't able to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with complex numbers.

Look at the number of holes in each digit

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 2 1
```

Now look at the total number of holes when you write the number in the usual way;
just take the weighted sum of the digits.

Comment: Edited only to align the table (insert quadruple space before each line).  But it looks to me like the digit 9 has one hole, not zero.$$ $$I'm reminded of the GRE question I heard of last week(?): Which of the following shapes is simple connected?  (A)a (B)b (C)c (D)d (E)e

Comment: Yet more evidence that case matters.  Gerhard "aSK mE aBOUT sYSTEM dESIGN" Paseman, 2012.04.04